# XML Serialization Using XMLElement

Tags: c#, xml

I have a defined class that has the following data

```
public partial class EHRNodesTesting {
   private string fieldID;
   private bool fieldRights;
   private string fieldName;

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
   public string FieldID
   {
      get { return this.fieldID; }
      set { this.fieldID = value; }
   }
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
   public bool FieldRights 
   {
      get { return this.fieldRights; }
      set { this.fieldRights = value; }
   }
   [XmlElement("Value")]
   public string FieldValue
   {
      get { return this.fieldName; }
      set { this.fieldName = value; }
   }
}
```

Then I populate this using a set of data I get so I have no predefined fields and on serialize the results is as follows

```
<FieldNode>
   <FieldName FieldID="LastName" FieldRights="true">
      <FieldValue>Harris</FieldValue>
   </FieldName>
   <FieldName FieldID="FirstNameName" FieldRights="true">
      <FieldValue>John</FieldValue>
   </FieldName>
</FieldNode>
```

Now, Is there a way that serialization takes the value of FieldID and replace FieldName with it to get the following

```
<FieldNode>
   <LastName FieldID="LastName" FieldRights="true">
      <FieldValue>Harris</FieldValue>
   </LastName >
   <FirstName FieldID="FirstName" FieldRights="true">
      <FieldValue>John</FieldValue>
   </FirstName>
</FieldNode>
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're asking, but if you're trying to modify the node name, `XmlNode.Name` is a **read-only** attribute. Consider creating the xml yourself. See [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Comment: I find the the node name normally relates to a property or the class, so consider naming either accordingly

Comment: so looking like no way to setup a rule to do that other than creating own xml

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with XmlDocument/XDocument objects. Have you tried customizing output by implementing `IXmlSerializable`? I am not experienced with limitations of the interface.

I do have an Xml-like custom serialization in which I can change the node's name. I believe you would have to do the same.